# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.5

magento upgrade 1.5.1.0 >> {1.6.2.0,1.7.0.2,1.8.0.0}  i was trying to remove all modules, upgrading directly copying files and with magento downloader, no luck,
every time i get this error. but where and why it fails exactly, how to debug it properly?

```
Error in file: "Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" 
- SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Trace:
#0 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.8.28', '1.6.0.3')
#2 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.8.28', '1.6.0.3')
#3 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 Z:\home\www\store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 Z:\home\www\store\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 Z:\home\www\store\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: Are you sure your PDO mysql is enabled? check your phpinfo() output.

Comment: error would be then:
The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded. the problem was in some table name it had '?' in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable PDO MySQL Debug need to edit this file:
/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

```
protected $_debug               = true;
```

then we open this file:
/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php, and replace this line about 234:

```
throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($e->getMessage(), (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
```

with this code:

```
$msg = "SQL ERROR: ". $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            $msg .= "SQL QUERY:" . $this->_stmt->queryString."\n";
            if(!empty($params)) {
                $msg .= "SQL PARAMS: ('". implode("','", $params) ."')\n";
            }
            $dbsEx = new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($msg, (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
            throw $dbsEx;
```

so now we will get a folder /var/**debug**/, and file **pdo_mysql.log**
in this file we have now full mysql error with full mysql query.
you can easily execute those failing queries in phpmyadmin or edit database table, params, etc.

im happy with it.